# SqlDataReader returning incorrect value and types

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to fill a List with objects. Those objects contain information in the following format:

```
class record
{
    //klassen variable 
    private string voornaam;
    private string recordtype;
    private decimal gewicht;
    private string datum; 

    public string Voornaam
    {
        get { return voornaam; }
        set { voornaam = value; }
    }
    public string Recordtype
    {
        get { return recordtype; }
        set { recordtype = value; }
    }

    public decimal Gewicht
    {
        get { return gewicht; }
        set { gewicht = value; }
    }
    public string Datum
    {
        get { return datum; }
        set { datum = value; }
    }
```

These classes will be filled with information coming from a SQL table. I use this code to get the information and fill the list:

```
public List<record> GetAllRecords()
{          
    List<record> records = new List<record>();
    using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = 
(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = " + database + "; Integrated Security = True;"))
    {
        Connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [records]", Connection);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string voornaam = reader.GetString(1);
                string oefening = reader.GetString(2);
                decimal gewicht = reader.GetDecimal(3); <--this is the problem
                string datum = reader.GetString(4);
                record Record = new record(voornaam, oefening, gewicht, datum);
                records.Add(Record); 
            }
        }
        Connection.Close();
        return records;
    }
 }
```

I do this to fill a listbox in windows forms with all the class information. However this is not possible because I get the error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'.

I understand the error, I cannot fit the decimal in the list because it has to be a string. But my sql table contains a decimal and my class also does. So I can't use `ToString()` or convert it. Should I use another approach and if so how?

Comment: To be clear, lists have nothing to do with your issue and not the it really matters, but I believe the more appropriate term for what you call 'classes', is 'objects' . Also for the future, try to post all relevant code--the constructor for `record` is absent. Although it can be inferred from the usage you show, that's not always the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns of your `SqlDataReader` are 0-based, not 1-based, so you should retrieve your data, starting with column 0, not with column 1

```
string voornaam = reader.GetString(0);
string oefening = reader.GetString(1);
decimal gewicht = reader.GetDecimal(2);
string datum = reader.GetString(3);
```

The  error message just say following: you are getting `string` column (`datum`), but you are trying to get is as `decimal`

Comment: and using ordinal-based columns in connection with `SELECT *` is asking for trouble. spell out the column names or access them by name.